# windows exporter does not collect metrics from other namespaces

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with Windows and Linux nodes and containers. For Linux I collect metrics normally with Prometheus but windows metrics are not displayed. I have installed and configured windows_exporter https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter. Metrics appeared for pods that are in the same namespace as windows_exporter. Could you please help me how to collect matrices from other namespace. Or advise how best to collect metrics from Windows AKS nodes and pods. Thanks.

Comment: You can refrer this documnent it may help to you : https://octopus.com/blog/export-metrics-from-windows-kubernetes-nodes-in-aks

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with the below steps :**

1. After Downloading the ***Windows-Exporter***,
   Open the folder in the terminal and run :

   ```
   .\windows_exporter.exe --collectors.enabled "cpu,cs,logical_disk,os,system,net"
   ```
2. Once the ***Windows-Exporter*** is started , ***Configure Prometheus
   for scraping the exporter*** by adding the below ***inside the
   `scrapes_configs` array***:

   ```
     - job_name: "windows_exporter"
       static_configs:
         - targets: ["localhost:9182"]
   ```
3. Now ,configure ***Prometheus*** to ***remote write*** by adding the
   below in the `root config`:

   ```
   remote_write:
     - url: "https://<PROMETHEUS_SERVER_NAME>/prometheus/remote/write"
       tls_config:
         insecure_skip_verify: true
   ```
4. Once, the above steps are performed you can ***start Prometheus***
   and if you want ***one day data retention or retention of data*** as
   per your requirement then you can run the below :

   ```
   prometheus.exe --storage.tsdb.retention.time=1d ##as per your requirement change 1d
   ```

**Reference:**

[Monitoring a Windows cluster with Prometheus – Sysdig](https://sysdig.com/blog/monitoring-windows-prometheus/)

### OR

As ***RahulKumarShaw-MT*** suggested you can refer [How to export metrics from Windows Kubernetes nodes in AKS - Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/blog/export-metrics-from-windows-kubernetes-nodes-in-aks) and [aidapsibr/aks-prometheus-windows-exporter](https://github.com/aidapsibr/aks-prometheus-windows-exporter)